# how to check if hidden field has no value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i make a hidden field and i want if hidden field has empty value then code run
here is my code:

```
 <input type="hidden" id="itemscounter" name="itemscounter" value=""/>

if ($('#itemcounter').val()==""){
            $('#itemscounter').val("1");
            var counter=$('#itemscounter').val();
            var quantity=$('#quantity').val();
            var unitprice=$('#unitprice').val();
            var linetotal=quantity*unitprice;
            that.parent().find('.linetotal').val(linetotal) 
            $("#invoicetotalamount").val(+linetotal)
            var discount=document.getElementById('discount').value ;
            var discountamount= discount/100 * linetotal;
            var amount=linetotal-discountamount;
            $("#balanceamount").val(+amount);
        }
```

Comment: It looks like you are doing that already.

Comment: Okay, so what's the question?

Comment: If the hidden field has the ID of `itemcounter` then your code is correct, is it placed within an event handler to execute it?

Comment: ID has a typo. It is `itemscounter` but in JS you are checking `val()` of `itemcounter`. Or do you have another input field with id as `itemcounter`?

Comment: `itemscounter !== itemcounter` both should be same change to check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a typo, your id is 'itemscounter', you are checking for 'itemcounter', also make sure you have put it within the `<script>` tags.

```
if ($('#itemscounter').val()==""){
        $('#itemscounter').val("1");
        var counter=$('#itemscounter').val();
        var quantity=$('#quantity').val();
        var unitprice=$('#unitprice').val();
        var linetotal=quantity*unitprice;
        that.parent().find('.linetotal').val(linetotal) 
        $("#invoicetotalamount").val(+linetotal)
        var discount=document.getElementById('discount').value ;
        var discountamount= discount/100 * linetotal;
        var amount=linetotal-discountamount;
        $("#balanceamount").val(+amount);
    }
```